# How to use Authorization and JWT with Istio

Tags: jwt, istio

In short summary I am planning on my services handling their own authorization as it relates to internal authorization ie… can the user have access to a particular object (content:1234)

What I believe is happening with Istio Security is it handles the following

1. It can validate the JWT token before any of my services are hit
2. It can authorize the request is allowed to call requested service
3. I believe I can actually generate the JWT token with Istio

I want to make sure I am right about the above AND ask 2 additional questions

1. I was planning on including roles in the token and that is how my services handle local security as I mentioned above ie… can the user access content:1234.
   Is this possible? How do I do this? Do I connect Istio to some code I write or a MicroServcie I write? Confused about this
2. I assume the JWT token will be on the request so I should be able to access it within my services behind Istio. Just making sure.

thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

1.

> It can validate the JWT token before any of my services are hit

No. Istio envoy filter is capable of performing checks on a JWT token that the Envoy Proxy will extract from the HTTP Request's headers. However validation (signing the JWT), You can set up OpenID Connect provider. For example a pod containing a [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/2018/02/keycloak-and-istio.html) Server.

---

2.

> It can authorize the request is allowed to call requested service

Yes, You can configure [`AuthorizationPolicy`](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) to do that. Here is an [example](https://istiobyexample.dev/authorization/).

---

3.

> I believe I can actually generate the JWT token with Istio

No. Same reason as question as the first question.

---

4.

> I was planning on including roles in the token and that is how my services handle local security as I mentioned above ie… can the user access content:1234. Is this possible? How do I do this? Do I connect Istio to some code I write or a MicroServcie I write? Confused about this

The answer #2 covers this.

---

5.

> I assume the JWT token will be on the request so I should be able to access it within my services behind Istio. Just making sure.

Yes, as long as the request is properly handled (headers are forwarded on each hop between each service) the JWT token should be in header.

---

There is article about JWT Authentication [here](https://dzone.com/articles/origin-authentication-and-rbac-in-istio-with-custo).

Hope it helps.